# How to verify code sent in passwordless authentication in Auth0 using API?

Tags: c#, .net, auth0, password-less

We can start the passwordless flow using the Auth0 .NET client like this:

```
var apiClient = new AuthenticationApiClient(new Uri(_appCredentials.Domain));

var result = await apiClient.StartPasswordlessEmailFlowAsync(new PasswordlessEmailRequest
        {
            ClientId = _appCredentials.ClientId,
            Email = email,
            Type = PasswordlessEmailRequestType.Code
        });
```

However, verifying the code

```
var token = await apiClient.GetTokenAsync(new AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest
{
    ClientId = _appCredentials.ClientId,
    ClientSecret = _appCredentials.ClientSecret,
    Code = code
});
```

Doesn't work. It doesn't seem that actually **verifying** the passwordless code is supported via their API. Is that correct? How do we verify the code from our end without embedding the Universal Login widget into our site?